# I need a shell script for below query

Tags: shell

I have 3 files a b c which have data given below. i want to consolidate these all files data in single file with shell script. I am using awk command but not getting the proper format of data please help me to resolve this.

file a

```
2019-02-08 1361

2019-02-09 1389

2019-02-10 1430

2019-02-11 1190
```

file b

```
2019-02-08 1005

2019-02-09 1145

2019-02-10 945
```

file c

```
2019-02-09 600

2019-02-11 333
```

Wanted Required Output

```
2019-02-08 1361 1005
2019-02-09 1389 1145 600
2019-02-10 1430 945 
2019-02-11 1190      333
```

Comment: Even you "not getting proper format of data", you should show your effort. At least it may make some answers easier to start, or just need to modify your code to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

`cat * >> output.txt` will comprise content of ALL files to the current directory in `output.txt`.

If your `a b c` files have some extension use it as `cat *.txt`

Comment: Sir i want parallel  data in in output.txt file